# Add SMDs for each level of a categorical variable in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary, smd

I would like to create a table one of baseline characteristics, stratified by an exposure, that shows SMDs between the exposure groups for **every level** of the categorical variables. Currently, adding SMDs via add_difference only gives an overall SMD for the variable as shown with Grade below.

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> Warning: package 'gtsummary' was built under R version 4.2.3

tbl <- 
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, response, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_difference(everything() ~ "smd")

tbl
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awA4t.jpg)

I cannot figure out how to make them as a custom function within gtsummary. Alternatively, `bal.tab()` from the cobalt package calculates them by level, but I also can't figure out how to add them to my tbl_summary from that package.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: The best way to do this is to use dummy variable coding for, in the example above, the grade column. Then you'll get the SMD for each level.

Comment: I don't understand what the .07 is for the Difference of the grade. Grade is categorical, so I don't see a meaning to "Difference" in the summary line (It *would* be nice to get summaries of the individual levels of the factor).

Comment: @MikeS, you're right - the "overall SMD" isn't exactly an SMD. It's a Mahalanobis distance between the two groups, which for binary variables simplifies to the SMD and can be interpreted as a sort of SMD for (polytomous) categorical variables. It can be very nice to have both things present simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The function is now incorporated into a package, which can be loaded with:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("zheer-kejlberg/Z.gtsummary.addons")
library(Z.gtsummary.addons)
```

---

I've written some code to do just this with gtsummary tables at https://github.com/zheer-kejlberg/gtsummary-SMDs.

Use `%>% add_SMD(location = "level")` to add SMDs to each level of all categorical variables or `%>% add_SMD(location = "both")` to get both the "overall SMDs" (Mahalanobis distances) and the per-level SMDs.

Behind the scenes, the function uses dummy coding for the per-level SMDs.

There's not as yet support for confidence intervals on SMDs, but that's in the pipeline. See the output here:

[image]

---

EDIT (Nov 12 2023):
The function has now been updated with support for confidence intervals (the `ci` argument) and custom number of decimals (the `decimals` argument).